# I can do the math but not the problems, help?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, soft-question

So whenever my instructor / teacher is going over the notes and teaching the new lesson to the class, I listen to what he says, take notes, and do the practice problems along with him. Often times I also answer many of the questions like 'What's the next step?' or 'What should the end of this step look like?' and even 'What's the final answer?'. I answer disproportionately more than the other students in my class and often get the answers correct. I also ask corollary questions to try to relate the material with past assignments or things that make sense to me. Sometimes I'll even do a problem on the board for the class if the instructor asks. But when I get the homework? I completely break down and stare at the questions and say 'What...?' I think I'm having trouble not with the math itself, but understanding the processes and steps in the formula. I just can't seem to remember them, and it's dragging down my grade. My question is, then, do any of you have the same problems and what has worked for you or others you know?

Comment: Some people learn best from reading, others from hearing. If you can understand and suggest the correct steps in lecture, but not when looking at the problem in the book, perhaps you need to read the book aloud, or even pretend you are giving a lecture in which you explain the problem and then describe its solution.

Comment: I have similar problem. I go blank in exams / quizzes . Assignments also become a pain at times. :(

Comment: Is there a fundamental difference between in class and those on your homework?  For example, are the in class questions straightforward "solve this equation", and the homework questions longer word problems that are making you think outside of the box?

Comment: @MJD We don't have or use a book, just lecture notes and worksheets.

Comment: @Teepeemm I think that there is. The questions on the notes, we largely work through as a class, as the instructor goes through step by step and asks for answers every step of the way. Worksheets are just simply a problem, with no labels or directions, nothing telling you what to do or what to find. That's what I think my biggest problem is. I don't make math errors, I just don't know what steps to do or what I'm supposed to solve for.

Comment: The advice is the same regardless.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, a lot of students suffer from this issue. The best thing to do is make sure you take really good notes. I know many students who write the steps out, each in a different color, the write a practice problem out step-by-step using the colors that correspond to that step. It is also helpful for them to put pop-out bubbles explaining what was done in each step. Some students even write out the steps and use the pop-out bubbles on their quizzes and tests to keep them on track.

Also, they say that the true test of knowledge is to see how well you can explain the things, so maybe you should try explaining the process to a sibling/parent/friend once you get home; if they understand, then you most likely do too. I understand that you perform well in class, but many students get things in class and forget or "blank" when they get home.

You are not alone in this, as many students have this same problem. It's just about figuring out what works for you.

-Caitlyn :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't "see" the problems right away — if you blank on homework problems, quizzes, or tests — **try talking yourself through the problem.**

For example, in my Calc. III class there are about six or seven tests we use which prove the convergence of series. On a recent quiz, I totally blanked for the first fifteen seconds. Then I thought to myself, "What tests can I try?" and I listed them off in my mind: "Can I use Test for Divergence? Can I use Integral Test? Can I use Limit Comparison Test? . . ." Finally, I realized L.C.T. would quickly prove the convergence of the series, and I correctly completed the first problem.

**List out possible approaches to each problem**; this trick usually gets me "jump-started" and I can breeze through the rest of the problem.